# Name of the process that causes ice to melt under pressure and refreeze after

Tags: terminology, ice

I remember a physics experiment from school where a wire with weights on each end was placed over a block of ice.

The pressure of the wire caused the ice to melt underneath and refreeze once the wire had passed.

Thus the wire passed through the block of ice - keep it whole.

I thought the term was "relegation" but am not sure now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds right except it's "regelation". And the experiment you're describing is found [right on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regelation)!

Comment: Thanks - my google search were returning only things about sports ;-) will accept when stack exchange lets me

Comment: Spelling helps.